# Propagate exception to enriching routes

Tags: java, apache-camel

I have 3 routes:

- `route-file1` which reads `file1.csv` and converts to array
- `route-file2` which reads `file2.csv` and converts to array
- `route-final` which uses enrich of both routes (with custom aggregator to merge arrays) and do something

Problem is if `route-file1` succeeds, but `route-file2` or any other routes fail. `route-file1` already completed and moved `file1.csv` to `.done` folder, so I cannot rerun everything again.

Is there a way that when `route-final` fails, it propagates exception to other routes used in enrich? I tried using transaction which works fine with stopping the route execution, but does not propagate exception to the `route-fileX` routes. Is this possible with the camel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set `shareUnitOfWork` to true in your content-enricher's so they work together in the same unit of work. See more details in the documentation: http://camel.apache.org/content-enricher.html

Comment: One small question. Once I enable unitOfWork to true, it seems that all exchange share same properties... is this true?